# postgres "ntile(2) over (order by column)" invalid order

Tags: postgresql

I've noticed strange behavior using postgres ntile on big table. It does not really order correctly. The example is:

```
select tile, min(price) as minprice, max(price) as maxprice, count(*) 
from (
    select ntile(2) over(order by price ASC) as tile, adult_price as price
    from statistics."trips"
    where back_date IS NULL AND adult_price IS NOT null
    and departure = 297 and arrival = 151
) as t
group by tile
```

It gaves really strange result by my opinion:

```
tile    minprice    maxprice    count
1       2250        5359        74257
2       2250        27735       74257
```

nothing special about count and maxprice. It could be correct for some data sets. But min_price shows that something is wrong with the ordering.

How can be min_price of 2nd tile less than max_price from 1st? But this is approved by checking result of internal select. It is ordered only partially and has some "mixed" parts where price order is broken.

Splitting in 2 parts manually shows the same min and max price, but different middle prices:

```
select * from (
    select row_number() over (order by adult_price ASC) as row_number, adult_price
    from statistics."trips"
    where back_date IS NULL AND adult_price IS NOT null
    and departure = 297 and arrival = 151
    order by price
) as t
where row_number IN(1, 74257, 74258, 148514)

row_number adult_price
1          2250
74257      4075
74258      4075
149413     27735
```

Answer (score 0):

It must be the confusing column names.

The column `price` in the outer query is actually `adult_price` in the inner query, and the `ntile` is calculated ordering by a different column (`price` in the inner query).